# How long will the AWS RDS outage take when enabling backups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds, database-backups

We have AWS RDS database (mariadb) with backups disabled ( the retention is set to 0).

The documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html) states that in case of changing the retention period from 0 to some positive number, there will be an outage. Unfortunately i cannot find any info on how long will it be.

This is a production db for high availability service - and I do not want it to take like an hour or so.

The db size is significant - about 100 GB.

Does anyone know how long can it take?

Comment: "The db size is significant - about 100 GB." - that seems quite small

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html) suggests trying it on a test instance and I think that is the closest of a concrete answer you will get. The downtime will be merely the time needed to reboot the database.

Although the outage is expected to be minimal, if this really is an issue for your use case, you could maybe look into [replication methods with automatic failover](https://hevodata.com/learn/aws-rds-replication).